# Run a process on each worker before starting a job / tasks

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to figure out a way to start / run an external process in all workers before starting the jobs / tasks.

Specific use case - my job hits a service running on the node (localhost). The service itself is run via a docker container. I want to start the docker container before starting the tasks on a worker and then stop the container after all the jobs are done.

One approach could be to do `rdd.mapPartitions`, but that is at a executor level and I cannot cleanly do a stop as another partition might be executing on the same node. Any suggestions?

As a workaround, currently I start the docker containers while starting up the cluster itself, but that does not allow me to work with multiple different containers that may be required for different jobs (as in that case all containers will be running at all the time taking up node resources.)

Comment: Why don't you write script for your requirement?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan - my spark clusters are dynamically provisioned when jobs are submitted. As mentioned, currently I do script it, but bringing up the service as part of a cluster bootstrap. But if I can control this from spark, I can bring up the service as per the specific job and reuse the brought up cluster for another job that might require a different service to be up.